# Express-Validator check POST response from external API (including session and request)

Tags: json, node.js, express, express-session, express-validator

I've got a simple form with name and email.

I have to send those data to an external API (why i use request).

In form i use action="/send" to use route.post('/send' ...

Data from will be post and i get datas from the API back (like error for name or mail or just success) but it take the user also to /send.

But i like to keep the user on the page he current is and throw the errors there.

So on, i got some examples with express-validator and express-session.
But no example for how to use validator with response Data from an external API and to use the messages from this API.

Here is what i have at the moment:

Could be any page

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Request.get("https://cmediaapi.datingpartner.com/content/v3_real/profile/" + req.param("id"), (error, response, data) => {
      if(error) {
          return console.dir(error);
      }
      // console.dir(JSON.parse(data));
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      // console.dir(obj[1].pseudo);
      res.render('user', {
        title: 'Chat',
        user: obj,
        success: false,
        errors: req.session.errors
      });
      req.session.erros = null;
    });
});
```

And her is the send.js

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

var dp = '7daz1bba1';
var key = '256e5a83-40b7-4fd0-846b-71f415926957';

console.dir(req.body.pseudo.val);
console.dir(req.body.email.val);

Request.post(
'https://media.datingpartner.com/signup/webmaster.php?dp='+dp+'&app_key='+key+'',
{ form: { user: req.body.pseudo.val, email: req.body.email.val} },
    function (error, response, data) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.dir(data);
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.dir(obj.data);
        console.dir(obj.data.errors);

        if (obj.data.errors) {
            console.log('there is a error');
            var email = obj.data.errors[0];
            console.log(email);
            var msg = email[1];
            console.log(msg);

            req.session.errors = obj.data.errors;
            req.session.success = false;
            // res.send(msg);
        }
        else {
            req.session.success = true;
        }
    } 
    }
);

backURL = req.header('Referer') || '/';
res.redirect(backURL);
```

})

and my little try out form in PUG/Jade

```
div#content
    form(action="/send" method="POST")#signup
        input(name="pseudo[val]")
        br
        input(name="email[val]")
        br
        input(type="submit")
    div#results
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li #{error.msg}
```

It would be awesome if any one knows how to handle those external APIs to get errors on the same page without redirecting the user (only after success).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using `action="/send"`, try using `action="send()"` and declare this function using [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) from Jquery.
This will allow you to hit your url **POST /** with user data and return either success or error messages without having to reload the page.

I understand that the question was asked under Node and Express but this is a client-side issue, not a backend one so using Jquery can be use for this.